# Learning Java and Stuck on how to create an array from the elements within a for each loop

Tags: java, arrays

I am learning Java and I have the following code:

```
public Slide[] thisIsASlide (String [] slider) { 
    for (String amount : slider) { 
        Slide st = thisNewMethod(slider, 20,20);
    } 
   return ; 
}
```

The elements will be stored into amount at each iteration. I want to put this amount into a new array and return it. Please can someone help?

Thanks

Edit: I think I said this wrong I need to know how to put the variable of Slide (st) into a new array and return it. Please can someone help with this?

Comment: What book you using for learning Java?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I'm learning from Heads First Java but also trying to write as much code as I can and do other projects as much as I can.

Comment: Great, just make sure you don't add features or syntax to the language while using it.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi so it's not possible to put the elements from amount into an array and return it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Slide[] thisIsASlide (String[] slider) { 
    // create an slide array the same length as your incoming array
    Slide[] slides = new Slide[slider.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < slider.length; ++i) {
        // Add a slide at index i for each string at index i in the incoming array
        slides[i] = thisNewMethod(slider[i], 20, 20);
    }
    // return the created array
    return slides;
}
```

Comment: thanks I was thinking something similar to this but this doesn't use the for each loop that I have above. I just want the amount to be stored in an array and return it not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only define a local variable and never actually assign the value.

```
Slide st = thisNewMethod(slider, 20,20);
```

st in this case is your local variable. Since your forEach loop, does not provide an index where it currently is, it will not assign this to your array of sliders.

I hope this makes sense.

This post, explains the differences rather well:

[Foreach vs common for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788316/foreach-vs-common-for-loop)